# Adding downloaded fonts to TinyMCE

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, tinymce

i am using React and I'm trying to integrate TinyMCE into my website. Everything seems to be working fine, the one thing that i'm struggling with is adding custom fonts. The [tinyMCE blog](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-custom-font-family/) on adding custom fonts focus alot on Google fonts but i have a font that i have downloaded.

I don't have many `.css` files because i'm using tailwind CSS.

Here is the font situated in `index.css`:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "metrischmedium";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.eot");
  src: url("./assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.eot?#iefix")
      format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("./assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.svg#metrischmedium")
      format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

//among other font imports
```

What ive tried:

```
<Editor
            onInit=...
            initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor.</p>"
            init={{
              height: ...,
              menubar: ...,
              plugins: ...,
              font_formats:
                "Metrisch Light = Metrisch-light;Metrisch Medium = metrischmedium",
              toolbar:...,
              menu: ...,
              content_css: "../index.css", //trying to add all fonts in the file.
              content_style:
                "body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,metrischmedium; font-size:14px }",
            }}
          />
```

I've also tried importing it in like so:

```
tinymce.init({
  /* ... */
  content_style:
    "@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap');",
});
```

but it doesn't work as mine is not a url type font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Can you try using `public/**` folder instead of `src/**` for import of font files in your `index.css`
2. Then update your paths for font-face

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "metrischmedium";
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.eot");
  src: url("/assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("/assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("/assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
    url("/assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("/assets/fonts/Metrisch-Medium-webfont.svg#metrischmedium") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

3. Now, import `index.css` in the component where you are using TinyMCE

When your application is built for production, all the contents of the public directory are usually copied to the build output as-is, making the files available to be served directly.

Beware of any other file path corrections needed to this change.

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, you said that i should move the index.css to the public folder? I did that, updated the paths and imported it to the page im using tinyMCE on. I got the following errors ```Module not found: Error: You attempted to import ../../public/index.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean move font-files. Currently you have font url as `./assets/`. After moving font files to `public` and modify the import as `/assets/`. Keep your index file inside `src/**`.